# Ubuntu 12.04 LAN settings after changing ISP and modem : The Network Path was not found !

Tags: 12.04, networking, dhcp

There is probably a very simple answer to this but it has me stumped.

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 machine on a windows LAN.  Previously I could find the shared folders on the system by using `\\servername\sharename`. Recently I changed ISP's and as a result also the DHCP server/modem.  The old network was 10.0.0.1, the new one is `192.168.0.1`.

All the settings seem correct on the Ubuntu machine, and the DHCP has assigned the IP of 192.168.0.21, which I can ping without any loss of data. However when I try to connect using `\\servername\sharename` I get

```
The Network Path was not found !
```

I can access the internet from the Ubuntu machine without any problems, plus I can see and navigate to as well as open shared folders and files on all the windows machines on my LAN.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Impera,  where do I type this?  I am not familiar with linux

Answer (score 1):

Something like that was with me some monts ago !
Try that:

```
    sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

And you shold find something like:

```
    iface eth0 inet static 
    address 192.168.0.1 
    netmask 255.255.255.0 
    gateway 192.168.0.254 
    auto eth0
```

Copy all and save somwhere, after that, delete all from interface, save and restart 
If something wrong, change back your interface !

Comment: Type this in your terminal, Dash Menu and search Terminal, or use CTRL + ALT + F1 to F6, you can start at the same time 6 terminals, it's something like Command Line in Windows, to exit from Terminal use ALT + F7 !